# Add VBA solver constraints programmatically

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code that would loop through a column and add constraints to the solver model for each row where the cell value is 0.

So far I have tried this and it doesn't work.

```
For Each cell In Range("B11:B193").Cells
If cell.Value = 0 Then
SolverAdd CellRef:=(Cells.Address), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0" 
End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=(Cells.Address), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
```

To this:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=(cell.Address), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
```

UPDATE:

You like are getting that error due to your `For` line

Try updating to the following:

```
For Each Cell In Range("B11:B193")
    If Cell.Value = 0 Then
        SolverAdd CellRef:=(Cell.Address), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `For Each cell In Range("B11:B193", Range("0")).Cells
        SolverAdd CellRef:=(cell.Address), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
    Next cell`

Comment: I got an error Run0time error'1004' Method Range of object '_Global' Failed

Comment: A couple of things. `range.cells` doesn't do anything. `Range` and `Cells` are both ways to reference a cell or cells in the worksheet, but they don't work together. `Range("0")` doesn't mean anything in VBA.